# run a shell command (ctags) in cmake and make

Tags: cmake, ctags

I'm coding a c++ project in vim.

I'd like to run a `ctags` command (`ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .`) to generate references when I run make.

I think the way to do it is to use `add_custom_command` but I get confused on how to integrate it into CMakeLists.txt .

Comment: I'm not testing these answers anymore. ctags takes time on my ultra low power i5 so i just call it from vim once in a while.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most basic way to do this is:

```
set_source_files_properties( tags PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
add_custom_command ( OUTPUT tags
    COMMAND ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q . 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )
add_executable ( MyProjectOutput tags )
```

The first line tells `CMake` that `tags` will be generated.  The `add_custom_command` is `CMake` will generate `tags` when needed, and finally, some target needs to depend on `tags`.  The default working directory is in the build tree, so `WORKING_DIRECTORY` must be set to your source tree.  This is equivalent a Makefile entry:

```
tags:
    ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .

MyProjectOutput: tags
    # Whatever here...
```

Comment: just to make sure, `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is specified by default. I don't need to specify it. right?

Comment: Yes, `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is automatically set to the _current_ source directory (may be a subdirectory, if you are recursively adding source files).  `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is usually the directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` file is located.

Comment: CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR is the path to the top level of the source tree.

Comment: Note that `set_source_files_properties(tags PROPERTIES GENERATED true)` is [redundant](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#command:add_custom_command). Quote from `CMake` documentation: *`OUTPUT`: (...) Each output file will be marked with the `GENERATED` source file property **automatically***.

Answer (score 9):

**New solution:**

I think CMake changed since the previous answer was given.
Here is the lines I added in my CMakeLists.txt (tested with version 2.8.12):

```
# Add "tags" target and make my_project depending on this target.
set_source_files_properties(tags PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
add_custom_target(tags
    COMMAND ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
add_dependencies(my_project tags)
```

And it works perfectly now!

Comment: Hi Creak, this got flagged as not an answer. Did this solve your problem or are you asking a question. If solving a problem, can you edit your post and clarify so other people don't accidentally flag it? If asking a question, can you remove this and see [ask] for more details? Hope this helps, and good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253 : Sorry Creak , I didn't read your post correctly. I have no idea on how to undo flagging (You've made an error and you don't want to attract a moderator attention anymore....).

Comment: @jmort253: I changed my comment, it is definitely an **answer** and **not a question**.

Answer (score 8):

Daniel's and Creak's answers got me started, but I ended up with a more complex solution that I thought I'd share:

```
# Add a top-level "tags" target which includes all files in both
# the build and source versions of src/*.
set_source_files_properties(tags PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
add_custom_target(tags
    COMMAND ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND ln -sf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tags ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# ...but only make it a dependency of the project if the ctags program
# is available, else it will fail to build on Windows.
find_program(CTAGS_PATH ctags)
if(CTAGS_PATH)
    message(STATUS "Found ctags: ${CTAGS_PATH}")
    add_dependencies(MyProjecct tags)
endif(CTAGS_PATH)
```

It does several things that the simpler solutions do not:

1. It only adds "tags" as a dependency of the primary build product (`MyProject`) if there is actually a `ctags` program on the system. We don't want to break the build just because this is Windows, or because `ctags` simply hasn't been installed yet on the build system.
2. It extracts symbols from source files in both the build and source directories. This matters in a couple of cases.

   First, you might be using [`configure_file()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html?highlight=configure_file) and come from an Autotools background, so you've named your true source files `*.in`, which means `ctags -R` won't scan them. You need it to scan the generated versions in the build directory. For example, you might have `src/mainheader.h.in` in your source tree, with the project version number automatically subbed into it as `build/src/mainheader.h`.

   Second, some of your "source" files might be generated by other tools. In my current project, I have a couple of C++ header files that are generated by Perl scripts. I want symbols from both the generated headers *and* the Perl scripts in the tags file.
3. It works in a subdirectory.

   In the project I'm working on right now, the primary build product is made from `src/*` relative to the project root, and I only want symbols from that subtree in the tags file. I don't want it to include symbols from the unit tests, the examples, or the utility scripts.

   Because it is designed to run in a subdirectory, it creates a symlink to the `src/tags` file in the top of the build directory, so that `vi -t TagName` works. (I'm assuming here that if `ctags` exists, `ln` does, too.)