# Any equivalence of 'ldd' command in cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake

Is there anyway in cmake to do something like 'ldd', i.e., given a target, get its linked libraries, and store them in a list?

If there is not, is there a way to do a command line 'ldd' (i know using COMMAND) and store the output to a cmake variable?

Thanks

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827208/run-a-shell-command-ctags-in-cmake-and-make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I pretty much get it

```
include(GetPrerequsites)
```

and use function
    GET_PREREQUISITES

see this: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-June/029975.html

Answer (score 1):

Since CMake 3.16, `GET_PREREQUISITES` is deprecated. Use `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)` instead.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies